# Rails route path inside as hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to define constant `REDIRECT_DEFINITIONS` with application paths as a key. This constant is inside of shared controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class SignupBaseController < ApplicationController
  REDIRECT_DEFINITIONS = {
    test_results: {
      new: edit_users_experience_level_path(@current_user),
      create: edit_users_experience_level_path(@current_user),
    },
    experience_levels: {
      edit: new_users_identity_check_path,
    },
    "users/identity_checks": {
      new: root_path,
    },
    default: request.referrer || root_path,
  }.freeze
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
undefined method `edit_users_experience_level_path' for SignupBaseController:Class
```

EDIT:

routes.rb:

```
  namespace :users do
    resource :dashboard, only: :show
    resource :identity_check, only: %i[new create show]
    resources :experience_levels, only: %i[edit update]
  end
```

Comment: Please can you supply your `config/routes.rb` file (specifically the line or lines pertaining to users_experience_level)

Comment: @mattp question updated

Comment: In your case you should add a method to handle redirect instead of constant.

Comment: path helpers are only available inside controller/view contexts. Although you have this in a controller file, it's not in the context of a request (e.g. a controller action or a hook)

Answer (score 0):

Include url_helpers in controllers as below, so that you can have access to all the routes/url of the application.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class SignupBaseController < ApplicationController
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  
  REDIRECT_DEFINITIONS = {
    test_results: {
      new: edit_users_experience_level_path(@current_user),
      create: edit_users_experience_level_path(@current_user),
    },
    experience_levels: {
      edit: new_users_identity_check_path,
    },
    "users/identity_checks": {
      new: root_path,
    },
    default: request.referrer || root_path,
  }.freeze
```